# Convert Pandas Series of 2D numpy arrays to Pandas DataFrame of columns of 1D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

First post to stackoverflow. I have searched an cannot find an answer to this.

I have a Pandas Series of 2D numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x1 = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[3,4]],dtype=np.uint8)
x2 = np.array([[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]],dtype=np.uint8)

S = pd.Series(data=[x1,x2],index=['a','b'])
```

The output S should look like:

```
a    [[0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
b    [[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

I wish to have it transformed into a Pandas DataFrame D where each column of the 2D numpy array in S becomes a 1D numpy array in a column of D:

D should look like:

```
     0        1
a    [0,2,3]  [1,3,4]
b    [5,7,9]  [6,8,10]
```

Note, my actual data set is 1238500 arrays sized (32,8) so i was trying to avoid iterating over rows.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution with [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and `map`

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.stack(map(np.transpose, S)).tolist(), index=S.index)

print (df)

           0           1
a  [0, 2, 3]   [1, 3, 4]
b  [5, 7, 9]  [6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: This is a nice approach. As a pedantic point, each cell contains a list rather than a numpy array. You may want to `.applymap(np.array)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? .applymap on the final DF?

Comment: If you want numpy arrays inplace of lists then you can use `df = df.applymap(np.array)`

Answer (score 1):

You can split and squeeze without ever converting the last dimension to a python list.

```
df = S.apply(np.split, args=[2, 1]).apply(pd.Series).applymap(np.squeeze)

           # 0           1
# a  [0, 2, 3]   [1, 3, 4]
# b  [5, 7, 9]  [6, 8, 10]
```

In `args=[2, 1]`, `2` stands for the number of columns and `1` stands for the axis to slice across.

Types:

```
In [280]: df.applymap(type)
Out[280]: 
                         0                        1
a  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
b  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
# flatten the list
S = S.apply(lambda x: [i for s in x for i in s])

# pick alternate values and create a data frame
S = S.apply(lambda x: [x[::2], x[1::2]]).reset_index()[0].apply(pd.Series)

# name index
S.index = ['a','b']

     0          1
a   [0, 2, 3]   [1, 3, 4]
b   [5, 7, 9]   [6, 8, 10]
```